# Python/NumPy: implementing a running sum (but not quite)

Tags: python, numpy, sum, iteration, convolution

Given are two arrays of equal length, one holding data, one holding the results but initially set to zero, e.g.:

```
a = numpy.array([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1])
b = numpy.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

I'd like to compute the sum of all possible subsets of three adjacent elements in a. If the sum is 0 or 1, the three corresponding elements in b are left unchanged; only if the sum exceeds 1 are the three corresponding elements in b set to 1, so that after the computation b becomes

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1])
```

A simple loop will accomplish this:

```
for x in range(len(a)-2):
    if a[x:x+3].sum() > 1:
        b[x:x+3] = 1
```

After this, b has the desired form.

I have to do this for a large amount of data, so speed is an issue. Is there a faster way in NumPy to carry out the operation above?

(I understand this is similar to a convolution, but not quite the same).

Answer (score 6):

You can start with a convolution, choose the values that exceed 1, and finally use a "dilation":

```
b = numpy.convolve(a, [1, 1, 1], mode="same") > 1
b = b | numpy.r_[0, b[:-1]] | numpy.r_[b[1:], 0]
```

Since this avoids the Python loop, it should be faster than your approach, but I didn't do timings.

An alternative is to use a second convolution to dilate:

```
kernel = [1, 1, 1]
b = numpy.convolve(a, kernel, mode="same") > 1
b = numpy.convolve(b, kernel, mode="same") > 0
```

If you have SciPy available, yet another option for the dilation is

```
b = numpy.convolve(a, [1, 1, 1], mode="same") > 1
b = scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_dilation(b)
```

**Edit**: By doing [some timings](https://gist.github.com/2283089), I found that this solution seems to be fastest for large arrays:

```
b = numpy.convolve(a, kernel) > 1
b[:-1] |= b[1:]  # Shift and "smearing" to the *left* (smearing with b[1:] |= b[:-1] does not work)
b[:-1] |= b[1:]  # … and again!
b = b[:-2]
```

For an array of one million entries, it was more than 200 times faster than your original approach on my machine.  As pointed out by EOL in the comments, this solution might be considered a bit fragile, though, since it depends on implementation details of NumPy.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to suggest, but 30 seconds faster. ;)

Comment: On the OP's `a`, this is actually slower, but as the array grows it seems to get much better.

Comment: +1: NumPy's features are put to very good use, here. Elegant and efficient code.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I fixed your last solution, which gave an incorrect result. It's quite subtle, but `b[1:] |= b[:-1]` does not give the same result as `b[:-1] |= b[1:]`: the first form does not do what you intended, because the updated b values are used in the calculation. The last solution appears to be implementation dependent, as b is modified while being used: it works only if the NumPy internal loop does not clobbers the original `b` values with their updated value during the OR calculation, which depends on whether the NumPy internal loop goes from the first element to the last one, or not.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Using `kernel = numpy.array([True]*3)` allows one to directly end the second solution with `b = numpy.convolve(b, kernel, mode="same")` (no need for another loop over the result for calculating `> 0`). This is slightly faster (maybe 10 % faster).

Comment: @EOL: Thanks for pointing out the error in the last code snippet.  I think your fix almost fixed it, giving a result shifted by one to the left.  I updated it to not have this shift, and hope we finally got it right. :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Right. Or, more simply `b = numpy.convolve(a, kernel, mode="same") > 1`, as in your other solutions. This takes as much time (on 1 million elements).  I updated your answer.

Comment: @EOL: Isn't it shifted by one again now?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Oops, sorry! I reverted the answer back to your edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the "convolution" sums in an efficient way with:

```
>>> a0 = a[:-2]
>>> a1 = a[1:-1]
>>> a2 = a[2:]
>>> a_large_sum = a0 + a1 + a2 > 1
```

Updating `b` can then be done efficiently by writing something that means "at least one of the three neighboring `a_large_sum` values is True": you first extend you `a_large_sum` array back to the same number of elements as `a` (to the right, to the left and to the right, and then to the left):

```
>>> a_large_sum_0 = np.hstack([a_large_sum, [False, False]])
>>> a_large_sum_1 = np.hstack([[False], a_large_sum, [False]])
>>> a_large_sum_2 = np.hstack([[False, False], a_large_sum])
```

You then obtain `b` in an efficient way:

```
>>> b = a_large_sum_0 | a_large_sum_1 | a_large_sum_2
```

This gives the result that you obtain, but in a very efficient way, through a leveraging of NumPy internal fast loops.

**PS**: This approach is essentially the same as Sven's first solution, but is way more pedestrian than Sven's elegant code; it is as fast, however. Sven's second solution (double `convolve()`) is even more elegant, *and* it is twice as fast.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful replies. I don't understand some of the syntax, but I **DO** understand the double convolution - very nice! I'll implement it tomorrow and have a look at the speed improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You might also like to have a look at NumPy's `stride_tricks`. Using Sven's timing setup (see link in Sven's answer), I found that for (very) large arrays, this is also a fast way to do what you want (i.e. with your definition of `a`):

```
shape = (len(a)-2,3)
strides = a.strides+a.strides
a_strided = numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)
b = np.r_[numpy.sum(a_strided, axis=-1) > 1, False, False]
b[2:] |= b[1:-1] | b[:-2]
```

*After edit (see comments below) it is no longer the fastest way.*

This creates a specially strided view on your original array. The data in `a` is not copied, but is simply viewed in a new way. We want to basically make a new array in which the last index contains the sub-arrays that we want to sum (i.e. the three elements that you want to sum). This way, we can easily sum in the end with the last command.

The last element of this new shape therefore has to be `3`, and the first element will be the length of the old `a` minus 2 (because we can only sum up to the `-2`nd element).

The strides list contains the strides, in bytes, that the new array `a_strided` needs to make to get to the next element in each of the dimensions of the shape. If you set these equal, it means that `a_strided[0,1]` and `a_strided[1,0]` will both be `a[1]`, which is exactly what we want. In a normal array this would not be the case (the first stride would be "size-of-first-dimension times length-of-array-first-dimension (= shape[0])"), but in this case we can make good use of it.

Not sure if I explained this all really well, but just print out a_strided and you'll see what the result is and how easy this makes the operation.

Comment: Interesting. I guess that a simple `len(a)` is equivalent to your `a.shape[0]`, in this case, no?

Comment: Towards the end, you meant "the *second* stride would be "size-of-…"…", right?  The first stride is simply the size of a single element (in bytes).

Comment: Note that your answer only gives half of the answer: the values in your summed array must be used for creating a new `b` array as in the original question. With what code did you do your timing tests?

Comment: @1st: Yep.
@2nd: No, I don't think so. It depends on the memory order of course, but if you try e.g. `np.ones((3,3)).strides`, you'll see that the first stride is bigger in the default NumPy order.
@3rd: Ah, of course, obviously didn't read the problem well enough. This adds extra code that makes it slightly slower than the other options. I'll edit the answer, thanks EOL.